# Preservation of dates when migrating from On-Premises TFS to VSO using OpsHub

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am currently testing migration scenarios from On-Premises TFS 2012 to Visual Studio Online using the very recently released OpsHub tool. The process is working pretty smooth, however I am not sure if some of the behaviour I am experiencing is to be expected.

- Our sprint start and end dates are not migrated, they show up empty in VSO. I am not sure if this is the result of an error on my part, or expected?
- The burndown charts are not looking so cool anymore :), due to missing date fields in the tasks, I think this is a known limitation? But just wanted to verify this.

I have already read the documentation and realize that this might be what is described under limitations, but I just wanted to doublecheck since I am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the expected behavior.

Sprint start and end dates are not migrated

The activity and change dates are set to migration date.

Comment: Is this still the case?  Not having the correct dates is blocker for us adopting VSO.  Is there another migration tool that can enable this?